# Anyway to use @2x iPad image as @3x for iPhone 6+?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

My app is a universal app that has images for both the iPhone and iPad. When the iPhone 6+ came out, I wanted to support the new @3x images, but I didn't want my binary to balloon so I decided to use my iPad @2x images (which were large enough) for the @3x images for the iPhone 6+. In order to do this, I had to create an image asset catalog and place the iPad @2x image in the @3x slot.

What I've found out is that when I create the binary for my app, it creates a duplicate image and renames it with the @3x suffix. So for instance, if I have an iPad image Photo@2x, it will duplicate it and rename it to Photo@3x, thus causing my binary to still increase in size.

Is there a way I can reuse my iPad@2x images to work for my iPhone6+ @3x images without causing my binary to increase?

Comment: the file are different from each other, they have basically different names, like  `xxx@2x.png` vs. `xxx@3x.png`, obviously the two files request to be stored separately from each other... frankly, I don't understand how you could raise such question.

Comment: @holex with asset catalogs the file names are irrelevant and in fact no longer need 2x or 3x suffixes.

Comment: @holex a 2x iPad image is big enough to be a 3x iPhone 6 plus image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, after doing some research, I don't think asset catalogs were created to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish and I don't think it's possible. When I put a @2x image in the slot of an @3x image in an asset catalog, the @2x image just got duplicated with a @3x title when I created the binary.

Basically I just had to bite the bullet and create separate iPad images and @3x images. I think maybe Apple doesn't want to see you scaling down iPad images to fit lower sizes because scaling can cause distortion. Better to have the exact size I guess?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using device specific images.

That way you will have slots specifically for iPad images (standard and retina) and for iPhone images (standard, retina and retina hd).

Then it's just a case of allocating the correct image size to the correct slot.

After trying this it does create a duplicate image in the file system. But you can edit the json to point it at the same file and then just delete the duplicate.

Comment: How do you set a device specific image? Isn't this just an asset catalog?

Comment: Yes, in the asset catalog, in the image group. Go to the properties and select device specific.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, when you do that it just makes another copy of the image. i.e. it makes a copy of image@2x called image@3x.

Comment: No, it shouldn't do... One sec

Comment: @CoDEFRo ok, you can go into the JSON file and edit it. That's the only way I can think to do it. It created the duplicate when I copied across but when I went into the contents.json file I was able to change it to use the same file name and then delete the redundant file.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I think it creates the redundant file for a reason though, so the app can find a file named 3x when it needs it. I'm just wondering if it's possible to do that at run time.

Comment: @CoDEFRo no, the file name is irrelevant. That's the whole point of having the contents.json file. Any 2x 3x suffixes are completely irrelevant when using asset catalogs. Did you actually try what I suggested or are you just assuming I'm wrong without trying it?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to understand why it's making the duplicate. I think it does it for a reason and I don't think it's a bug.

Comment: Ok. Don't change the json then. In which case the answer to humour question is "you can't". Or you could try what I suggested which you don't seem to want to even though it answers your question. Up to you. Meh

Comment: What I'm worrying about your solution is that if I change the JSon and it doesn't produce the @3x file, then what's the point of doing it? I might as well just delete the asset catalog.

Comment: The asset catalog doesn't "produce" any images. Not sure what you mean by "it doesn't produce the @3x file". Do you mean that it won't get the right image at runtime? If so... Have you tried it yet? You seem very keen on telling me my method won't work without actually trying it. Especially when it takes about 5 seconds to change the json and about 5 seconds to put it back. Just try it and see what happens.